# mongoose query multiple operations in one request

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to use the $set, $addToSet and $inc at the same time for my report of sales and
tbh I'm not even sure if I did the right approach since it's not working.

once I send the request, the console gives me the error 404 but when I check the req.body the data was correct. so I was wondering if the problem is my query on mongoose because this was the first time I use multiple operations on mongoose query

```
export const report_of_sales = async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    console.log(req.body);
    try {
        if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) return res.status(404).json({ message: 'Invalid ID' });
        let i;
        for (i = 0; i < req.body.sales_report.length; i++) {
            await OwnerModels.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {
                $inc: {
                    total_clients: req.body.total_clients,
                    total_product_sold: req.body.sales_report[i].qty,
                    sales_revenue: req.body.sales_report[i].amount
                },
                $set: {
                    "months.$[s].month_digit": req.body.months[i].month_digit,
                    "months.$[s].targetsales": req.body.months[i].targetsales,
                    "months.$[s].sales": req.body.months[i].sales,
                },
                $addToSet: {
                    sales_report: {
                        $each: [{
                                identifier: req.body.sales_report[i].identifier,
                                product_name: req.body.sales_report[i].product_name,
                                generic_name: req.body.sales_report[i].generic_name,
                                description: req.body.sales_report[i].description,
                                qty: req.body.sales_report[i].qty,
                                amount: req.body.sales_report[i].amount,
                                profit: req.body.sales_report[i].profit
                            }]
                    }
                }

            }, {
                arrayFilters: [
                    {
                        "s.month_digit": req.body.months[i].month_digit
                    }
                ],
                returnDocument: 'after',
                safe: true,
            }, { new: true, upsert: true })
        }
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).json(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you are looking at the body, but you are actually using query parameter named `id`. This is probably undefined, which leads to `ObjectId.isValid(id)` returning `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are looking at the body, but you are actually using query parameter named id. This is probably undefined, which leads to `ObjectId.isValid(id)` returning `false`.

You should decide on whether to pass this data as a query param or in the request body and adjust your code accordingly.